# CodeIgniter Admin & User Login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a admin Login, if the login good > i come to my admin/dashboard. But now i try to have a second user panel under member/dashboard.

I want that i have only acess to admin/dashboard, if the user database table users > is_admin = 1. If i dont have is_admin = 1, i get an error message. Thats the begin from my code.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->lang->load('users');
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'lang:users_email', 'required|callback_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'lang:users_password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login/index');
        } else {
            $user = $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')))->get('users')->row();
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'email' => $user->email,
                'image3' => $user->image3,
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
                'username' => $user->username
            ));
            if($user->is_admin == 1)
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        else
            redirect('member/dashboard');
        }
    }

    public function check() {
        $user = $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')))->get('users')->row();
        if (!$user) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check', lang('users_invalid_email_or_password'));
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
            return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Really not that much clear what is your problem .

Comment: Its not a problem to make a is_admin form like if($user->is_admin == 1)
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            else
                redirect('member/dashboard'); The problem is, i can go to admin dashboard too.

Comment: `i get an error message` what is the error message your getting ?

Comment: For that, you need to add check in admin/dashboard that if user->is_admin == 1 then dashboard should be accessable.

Comment: Can you give me a Sample pls?

Comment: Don't use md5 for passwords as very very insecure these days use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create a password hash then to verify use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check query result

```
$user = $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')))->get('users');
if($user->num_rows()<1){
   //What you want to do here
   return false;
}
$user = $user->row();
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
   'email' => $user->email,
   'image3' => $user->image3,
   'user_id' => $user->user_id,
   'username' => $user->username
));
if($user->is_admin == 1)
   redirect('admin/dashboard');
else
   redirect('member/dashboard');
```

The problem should be resolved in this way